# Override them with styled components

Tags: reactjs, themes, styled-components, theming

I want to creare a template theme in React for my software suite and allow developers to customize the theme for each software they develop.

The theme will be shipped in a library using styled components

Here is an example of the code:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
`;

const TomatoButton = styled(ButtonStyled)`
  color: tomato;
`;

//This is the default template
const DefaultTemplate = () => {
  return <div>
    <ButtonStyled className='button'>Button</ButtonStyled>
    <TomatoButton className='tomato-button'>Button II</TomatoButton>
  </div>
}

//This is the template styled by developers
const DefaultTemplateStyled = styled(DefaultTemplate)`
  color: white;

  &.button{
    color: violet
  }

  &.tomato-button{
    color: black;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (<DefaultTemplateStyled />);
}

export default App;
```

In this app I cannot see the override of the styles, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In styled-components what you should do is pass the `className` propm like this:

```
//This is the default template
const DefaultTemplate = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ButtonStyled className={`button ${className}`}>Button</ButtonStyled>
      <TomatoButton className={`tomato-button ${className}`}>
        Button II
      </TomatoButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

All the other code is fine